# Large length string in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I noticed a problem with large length strings in `JTextField`.
When the string is longer than 9888 characters, the text is displayed on top of another text. Console output is empty.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField field = new JTextField(30);
        frame.add(field);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Why does this happen and how to solve this problem without limiting the maximum length of the field or using `JTextArea`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem when using a for loop to add over 10,000 char's to my JTextField. Your question though begs another question: why would you need this length of String in a JTextField?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"why would you need this length of String in a JTextField?"* I would have expressed that as: ***why*** would you need this length of String in a JTextField?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hm, maybe it depends on operating system? I tested that on Linux with java 8. Also I pasted and typed the text by hand.
The size of string is not important for me. I just wanted the field to work fine regardless of the size of the data being entered.
For me it is much more interesting why this problem arises.